# MATLAB cannot find its own libraries

Tags: installation, matlab

I am having a problem with a new installation of MATLAB (2012b) that is cannot find the base enumberation type Simulink.IntEnumType. The specific error text is:

```
specified superclass 'Simulink.IntEnumType' contains a parse error or cannot be found on MATLAB's search path, possibly shadowed by another file with the same name
```

I am quite sure there is no shadowing, so I suspect there is a problem with the installation. Any ideas what could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rookie mistake, the machine I had set up didn't have a Simulink license.

For anyone interested, simply using int32 as the superclass for enumerations works fine.